# How to make sum of rows value until sum value is 1.0 in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I am stuck with this SQL Server query; here is my set of records:

```
Name    Value
----    ----
abc      0.7
xyz      0.4
pqr      0.6
ijk      0.3
fgh      0.1
cde      1.0
uvw      0.8
```

I want a query which will give me sum of value until it reach 1.0 and greater
then continue same with next rows, like

```
Names         Value
-----         -----
abc,xyz       1.1
pqr,ijk,fgh   1.0
cde           1.0
uvw           0.8
```

Please help me with this query; I tried with partitions and recursive CTE, but nothing worked so far.

Comment: order is name or what ?

Comment: yes, order is name.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'order is name'. For example, if you order by name ASC you don't get 'abc,xyz'.

Comment: @S_Sky . . . SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Your results assume an ordering.  Do you have such a column?

Comment: I wanted to retrieve result set in that order original table was, how exactly I given in example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Your results assume a particular ordering and there is no column for the ordering.  The following assumes that such a column exists.  It is just called `id`.

This type of problem requires a recursive CTE (or some other iterative processing), as far as I know.  Here is one method:

```
with t as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from mytable t
     ),
     cte as (
      select top (1) seqnum, convert(varchar(max), name) as name, convert(decimal(10, 1), value) as value,
             (case when value >= 1.0 then 1 else 0 end) as is_new
      from t
      order by seqnum
      union all
      select t.seqnum, 
             (case when cte.value >= 1 then t.name else concat(cte.name, ',', t.name) end),
             convert(decimal(10, 1), (case when cte.value > =1 then t.value else t.value + cte.value end)),
             (case when cte.value >= 1 then 1 else 0 end) as is_new
      from cte join
           t
           on t.seqnum = cte.seqnum + 1
     )
select name, value as sum_value
from (select cte.*, lead(name) over (order by seqnum) as nextname
      from cte
     ) cte
where nextname is null or nextname not like name + '%';
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2e885202c242dde73583127719296382) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you so much, you given me what i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can also solve by using cursors you can see from  [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/37b92/5)

```
    DECLARE 
       @name VARCHAR(MAX), 
       @value FLOAT,
       @total FLOAT,
       @names VARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @total = 0.0;
    SET @names = '';

    DECLARE name_value CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT name, value FROM table_1;

    OPEN name_value;

    FETCH NEXT FROM name_value INTO @name, @value;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            IF (@total >= 0.999)
            BEGIN
              INSERT INTO temp_table_1 VALUES(@names, @total);
              Set @total = 0.0;
              Set @names = '';
            END
            Set @total += @value;
            Set @names += @name  + ',';
            FETCH NEXT FROM name_value INTO  @name, @value
        END

    CLOSE name_value;
    INSERT INTO temp_table_1 VALUES(@names, @total); 
    DEALLOCATE name_value;
   GO
    SELECT * FROM temp_table_1
GO
```

Comment: Thank you, it will realy helpfull.